# Finding and Proving the limit as x approaches infinity.

Tags: calculus

I need to evaluate the limit as x approaches infinity of $\dfrac{1-x^2}{x-2}$ and then prove it.

I have found the limit to be negative infinity.  Now to prove it I believe I need to find two subsequences that diverge to two different results and therefore prove that the limit actually does not exist.  Am I thinking correctly? If so I am stuck on what subsequences to choose.

Comment: What you've written is not consistent. You said that the limit is negative infinity (correct), but that you're trying to prove the limit does not exist. How are these compatible?

Comment: I understand and that is part of my question.  The proof part is to show that for every epsilon > 0 there exists M>0 s.t. the absolute value f(x) - L < epsilon.  Since this is not bounded below and approaches negative infinity does the Limit actually not exist.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
For some constant $a\in\mathbb R$ and some constant $n\in\mathbb R_{>0}$
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\Bigl(\frac{a}{x^n}\Bigr)=0$$

I would rather try the following approach (first divide by $x$)

> $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\Bigl(\frac{1-x^2}{x-2}\Bigr)=\lim_{x\to \infty}\Biggl(\frac{\frac{1}{x}-x}{1-\frac{2}{x}}\Biggr)=\frac{\lim_{x\to \infty}\bigl(\frac{1}{x}-x\bigr)}{\lim_{x\to \infty}\bigl(1-\frac{2}{x}\bigr)}=\frac{-\infty}{1}=-\infty$$